# watch a whole directory and print diff on file change

Tags: inotify, watch

Is there a way to easily watch a full directory for changes and print a diff when a file changed?

Context: I would like to discover the name of the options in KDE Plasma's configuration by watching `.config` when I do a change on the GUI. Since many files are handeld by KDE I prefer to watch the full directory, and since the file can be quite big printing a diff could be useful.

Some ideas: I guess I could create a git repo (potentially only following the folders I need) with all the config and use inotifywait to call `git diff` and `git commit` (actually I can maybe even manually call `git diff HEAD` after a change) but I'm curious to learn better solutions, for instance when the folder to watch is too big to duplicate it into a git repo. Guess it's not trivial since you need to read the file when it's accessed but before it's written…

Comment: KDE writes config files directly, so even if you know the file has changed, you won't have its previous version to print the diff. I can only think of creating a git repo elsewhere, watching the directory and whenever the file changes, `git commit` it. As for watching you could use inotifywait: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=inotifywait

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes it's what I thought. I'm doing that for now manually, it's working great with a small config. Not sure how et scales to bigger folders, at least git can select only some subfolders.

Comment: I won't post an answer, because a complete answer would be too long and complicated, but just a pointer: I would use a filesystem that supports snapshots, such as `btrfs`. You will need to automate your snapshots, of course. I recommend checking out SUSE's [`snapper`](https://en.opensuse.org/Portal:Snapper) which is a great tool for managing, automating and comparing snapshots. There are packages of this tool for other distros, but since I've used it only on SUSE machines, I cannot vouch for it on other distros, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Uhm, interesting trick indeed ^^ I guess that I will stay with my simple git setting but interesting idea for more complex settings!